# G++ / clang Linker issues, OSX

Tags: c++, macos, linker, g++, clang++

```
g++ -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -o ./bin/game -framework SFML -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -Iinclude main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Game::run()", referenced from:
      _main in main-1dfef1.o
  "Game::Game()", referenced from:
      _main in main-1dfef1.o
  "Game::~Game()", referenced from:
      _main in main-1dfef1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I've seen that this is a common error, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong here. I installed SFML in the frameworks `Library/Frameworks` folder on OSX (Yosemite) as instructed on the SFML site.  You can see my build command in the snippet above (I've actually tried a number of different variations of this). If I don't include the SFML stuff, I still get the error. With `-v` the output is: http://pastebin.com/WAGC76a2

I can't glean from that what may be causing this, though. Any ideas?

Comment: You're not linking with the definitions of those `Game` members.

Comment: The code is almost a line for line copy of what is here: https://github.com/Piepenguin1995/citybuilder/tree/master/Part%201%20-%20State%20Manager

The only difference is the directory structure:
`/include/*.hpp`
`/src/*.cpp`

Comment: The Game class constructor and destructor are defined so far as I can tell. The only oddity I can see is that we're including `game.hpp` as opposed to including `game.cpp` (actually as I was typing this out I went to change that and it seems to be working fine). But why can the person who wrote that include the `.hpp` while I cannot?

Comment: You can, and should, include the header/hpp file. That file does not provide the definitions for the members, only their declarations. You need to compile the "game.cpp" file and link with the result in order for the linker to find the definitions. Changing the command line so it ends with "-Iinclude game.cpp main.cpp" should be enough.

Comment: It's going to be a real pain to have to add every file I create to that command before compiling. Is there a better way?

Comment: The project you copied apparently uses `cmake`. There's also "regular" `make`, and XCode is a pretty good IDE.

Comment: Nvm, doing `./src/*` instead of `./src/main.cpp` worked.